# Why Youtube "channels" API don't return "contentOwnerDetails" data?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to make this call to Youtube **channels** API but the response is without **contentOwnerDetails**. What is the problem?

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2CcontentDetails%2CcontentOwnerDetails&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it needs `onBehalfOfContentOwner` parameter. My request was

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentOwnerDetails&id=CHANNEL_ID&onBehalfOfContentOwner=NETWORK_ID
```

And I was able to get

`"contentOwnerDetails": {
    "contentOwner": NETWORK_ID,
    "timeLinked": "2015-07-23T15:21:25.000Z"
   }`

Answer (score 0):

For your **GET** method URI

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2CcontentDetails%2CcontentOwnerDetails&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The JSON response is as follows

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "youtube.parameter",
        "reason": "authorizationRequired",
        "message": "The request uses the <code>mine</code> parameter but is not properly authorized.",
        "locationType": "parameter",
        "location": "mine"
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "The request uses the <code>mine</code> parameter but is not properly authorized."
  }
}
```

According to **YouTube Data API - Errors**

> 401 (unauthorized) - authorizationRequired - The request uses the mine
>   parameter but is not properly authorized.

**mine** parameter value has to be set to true to instruct the API to only return channels owned by the authenticated user. (boolean)

**Inference:** You don't have the authorization to the content from the content owner, i.e., the YouTube Channel owner has probably denied permission to your application from accessing the channels content.

It's a permission issue. **Where is the channelId in the URI?** should probably add it.

Comment: No, it's not a permission issue. I'm authorized and this is not the problem. I use this page ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it ) to make the request and I gave perimssions. The request is correct, without errors, so there is no a preblem with authentication. My question is why contentOwnerDetails is missing in response? It's included in "part" list. I need contentOwnerDetails.contentOwner to get id of the user.

Comment: what is the fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't own the channel the API will not return contentOwnerDetails. Since you're using `mine=true` parameter, you need to be properly authorized via OAuth first before the API will return contentOwnerDetails. See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

Comment: If I understad the "channels" API correctly it will return list of channels (in "item" attribute) that are owned by authorized user. So how can I see his Google user_id?