# Retrieving user content after signing in with google sign-in

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

The user is signed in via the sign-in api:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

onConnected has been called

How do you then interact with the google api (e.g. the YouTube api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/)

I'm getting an error saying "The request uses the **mine** parameter but is not properly authorized.". How do I let my youtube api calls know that I'm authenticated?

The following shows my youtube API call:

```
val playlistsListByChannelIdRequest: YouTube.Playlists.List = youtube.playlists().list(part);

playlistsListByChannelIdRequest.setPart(part);
playlistsListByChannelIdRequest.setMine(true)
playlistsListByChannelIdRequest.setMaxResults(25);
playlistsListByChannelIdRequest.setKey(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY)

val response: PlaylistListResponse = playlistsListByChannelIdRequest.execute();
playlists.addAll(response.items)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#youtube.api.RequestContextError):

> unauthorized (401) -authorizationRequired -The request uses the
>   **`mine`** parameter but is not properly authorized

Based from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38244551/8342742):

> **mine** parameter value has to be set to true to instruct the API to only return channels owned by the authenticated user. (boolean)
>
> **Inference**: You don't have the authorization to the content from the content owner, i.e., the YouTube Channel owner has probably denied
>   permission to your application from accessing the channels content.

Here are the key concept about [Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication)

> The YouTube Data API supports the [OAuth 2.0 protocol](http://oauth.net/2/) for
>   authorizing access to private user data. The list below explains some
>   core OAuth 2.0 concepts:
>
> - When a user first attempts to use functionality in your application that requires the user to be logged in to a Google Account or YouTube
>     account, your application initiates the OAuth 2.0 authorization
>     process.
> - Your application directs the user to Google's authorization server. The link to that page specifies the **`scope`** of access that your
>     application is requesting for the user's account. The **`scope`**
>     specifies the resources that your application can retrieve, insert,
>     update, or delete when acting as the authenticated user.
> - If the user consents to authorize your application to access those resources, Google returns a token to your application. Depending on
>     your application's type, it either validates the token or exchanges it
>     for a different type of token.

And how to obtain it will be answered [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application).

> Your application must have authorization credentials to be able to use
>   the YouTube Data API. This document describes the different types of
>   authorization credentials that the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
>   supports. It also explains how to find or create authorization
>   credentials for your project.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer! Unfortunately, I'm using Google Sign-In, not Oauth 2.0. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple days wracking my brain, I figured this one out. The secret was to create a Credential object calling setSelectedAccount with the account returned in handleSignInRequest and use that when I initialize the YouTube object. See the following code:

```
// Scope for accessing the user's youtube account
val YOUTUBE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube";

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val result: GoogleSignInResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

// This happens as a result of using Google Sign-In in for the first time by selecting a user
fun handleSignInResult(result: GoogleSignInResult) : Unit {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Get the account from the sign in result
        val account: GoogleSignInAccount? = result.signInAccount

        if (account != null) {
            // Store the account from the result
            mAccount = account.getAccount()

            getSubscription()
        }
    }
}

private fun getSubscription() {
    GetSubscriptionTask(this, YOUTUBE_SCOPE).execute(mAccount)
}

/**
 * AsyncTask that uses the credentials from Google Sign In to access Youtube subscription API.
 */
private class GetSubscriptionTask(val context: Context, val YOUTUBE_SCOPE: String) : AsyncTask<Account, Unit, List<Subscription>>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Account?): List<Subscription>? {

        // This part's misleading because it says "usingOauth2" even though we're using Google Sign-In
        val credential: GoogleAccountCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                context,
                Collections.singleton(this@GetSubscriptionTask.YOUTUBE_SCOPE));
        credential.setSelectedAccount(params[0]);

        // Global instance of the HTTP transport
        val HTTP_TRANSPORT: HttpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();

        // Global instance of the JSON factory
        val JSON_FACTORY: JsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        val youtube: YouTube = YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName("ChronoPlayer")
                .build();

        val connectionsResponse: SubscriptionListResponse = youtube
                .subscriptions()
                .list("snippet")
                .setMine(true)
                .execute();

        return connectionsResponse.getItems();
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(subscriptions: List<Subscription>): Unit {
        if (subscriptions != null) {
            // Get names of all connections
            for (sub in subscriptions) {
                // Got the subscriptions. Success!
            }
        }
    }
}
```